# Robot framework - No selenium

Tags: selenium, robotframework

As you can see Ive installed selenium but Robot is saying its not installed.

Any help please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SceAv.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need a tab space after Library and SeleniumLibrary is one word.

example:

```
Library  SeleniumLibrary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary
```

Try installing/upgrading aforesaid Library and then use `Library  SeleniumLibrary`
Inside your `***Settings***` section